# How to calculate the robust standard error of predicted y from a linear regression model in R?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, robust-standard-error

How can I calculate the robust standard error of the predicted *y* from a linear regression model in R? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking about? I don't think this question is answerable in its current form. I am aware or robust  'sandwich' errors, eg, but those are for you betas, not for predicted y.

Comment: Check out the `car` package.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to calculate a standard error of the estimate that is robust (against what)? If so, I'm not aware of and haven't been able to find a method, but either way, this question really needs clarification. It does no good to post an answer in the negative to address only one possible interpretation...

Comment: If you mean "heteroskedasticity-robust," then by definition it can't be a single number.

Comment: Which robust standard error do you mean? Please clarify.

Comment: heteroskedasticity (& autocorrelation)-robust standard error can be computed using 'sandwich' package of R. The you can use coeftest() function from 'lmtest' package to compute estimated coefficients. 'car' package is also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean heteroskedasticity-consistent standard errors.

From a fitted regression model, a predicted value is 
$$
\tilde y = \tilde X'\hat\beta
$$
Its variance is
$$
V(\tilde y) = V(\tilde X'\hat\beta)\\
V(\tilde y) = \tilde X' \hat V_\hat\beta \tilde X
$$
where $\hat V_\hat\beta$ is the estimated parameter covariance matrix.  The formula for a heteroskedasticity-consistent parameter covariance matrix is on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors).  The standard errors of the fitted values are the square root of the diagonals of this matrix.

Here is an example:

```
#Fake data
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100)
e = x1*rnorm(100)
y = 10+x1-x2+e
X = cbind(1,x1,x2)

#Linear model
m = lm(y~X-1)
summary(m)
betahat = as.matrix(coef(m))

#Non-HC standard errors of fitted values
se.yhat = sqrt(diag(X%*%vcov(m)%*%t(X)))
se = predict(m,se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit
all.equal(se,se.yhat)#Matrix formula gives same result as se.fit option of predict method for lm's

#Now getting se's of fitted values based on HC-robust paramter covariance matrix
ehat = residuals(m)
vcov.HC = solve(t(X)%*%X) %*% t(X)%*%diag(ehat^2)%*%X %*% solve(t(X)%*%X)

se.yhat.HC = sqrt(diag(X%*%vcov.HC%*%t(X)))

#Showing that this method replicates regression parameter standard errors as given by the coeftest function
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(m,vcov=vcovHC(m,type="HC0"))
sqrt(diag(vcov.HC))
```

The example here gives SE's for observed values, but you can put whatever you want into the X matrix, including a 1xp vector for a single observation.

You can't modify a `lm` object's $V_\beta$ matrix, because it isn't stored, rather it's called on the fly as requested.  But you can do so if you use `gam` from the `mgcv` package (you don't need to use semiparametrics necessarily)

```
#Respecifying as a gam in order to create an object from which you can use the predict method
library(mgcv)
mg = gam(y~X-1)
mg$Vp <- vcov.HC
    summary(mg)
    all.equal(as.numeric(predict(mg,se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit),se.yhat.HC)
```

This is convenient because you can now use the standard `predict` method with `se.fit=TRUE`

Comment: Interesting, but will not give correct standard errors for *prediction*. Sandwhich SE are useful for hypothesis testing about coefficients, not for prediction.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen ancient thread.  Curious what led you to unearth it.  Obviously sandwich SE won't make much difference for prediction intervals, but I'm not immediately seeing why they should be useful for a CI for a hypothetical new data point, as distinct from a test-set member.  Would your general approach be to explicitly model the heteroskedasticity?

Comment: if prediction intervals needed, I guess I would model the heteroskedasticity, maybe `gamlss`. I searched and found this as a useful reference for an answer I just wrote ...